Convert discrete rows into columns in excel
I have an output text file that is just a copy of shell output after a batch file is run. Limitations:

I do not have access to the original batch file so I cannot edit that.

I have to make changes to the output after it is created.


The batch file is a basic deletion script like so:
del "Z:\Filepath\Spreadsheet.xlsx" 
del "Z:\Filepath\Document.docx" 
del "Z:\Filepath\Image.jpg" 

The output looks like this
> del "Z:\Filepath\Spreadsheet.xlsx"  
> The system cannot find the path specified.  
> 
> del "Z:\Filepath\Document.docx"  
>  
>  
> del "Z:\Filepath\Image.jpg"  
> The system cannot find the path specified. > 

And I would like to have it in table formula for excel like below:
> del "Z:\Filepath\Spreadsheet.xlsx" | The system cannot find the path specified. 
> del "Z:\Filepath\Document.docx"    | 
> del "Z:\Filepath\Image.jpg"        | The system cannot find the path specified.

Note the second file (Document.docx) did exist and was deleted without a confirmation message, so there is a blank line there but this needs to be noted as a blank field in the column. So it is two lines to separate into columns, followed by a blank line and then that needs to run through the whole text file doing that to each set of two lines.
Excel text to columns does not seem to be able to handle this. Happy for any solution in or outside excel, noting that I don't have access to the original batch file to set up the output differently in the first place.

Give a try to the following formula-
=TAKE(WRAPROWS(A1:A8,3),,2)


